# Pillow pasting transparent image shows black image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, paste, transparent

I'm trying to use Pillow to paste an image with a transparent background onto a background image.

The background is a simple color background, and the transparent background image is as follows:

[The transparent image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWXXN.png)

The code I'm using is below (the path is deliberately incorrect):

```
backgnd = Image.open("images/background.png")
backgnd.convert("RGBA")
body = Image.open("images/Untitled.png")
body.convert("RGBA")

backgnd.paste(body, (0,0), body)
backgnd.show()
```

The resulting image is as follows:

[The resulting image, being all black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE4GL.png)

I've tried using the alpha_composite method, but it returns ValueError: image has wrong mode.

Comment: Please also post the code with the `alpha_composite` approach and both exact images, you're using. By now, I'd suspect "the transparent image" has no alpha channel at all!?

Comment: The code for the alpha_composite method is ```backgnd.putalpha(1)
    body.putalpha(1)
    result = Image.alpha_composite(backgnd, body)
    result.show()```

Answer (score 1):

Try: `backgnd.paste(body, (0,0), mask=body)`